# Call to undefined method Redis::delete() on CakePHP 2.10.24

Tags: php, redis, cakephp-2.0, phpredis

I'm running an application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk PHP 7.3 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.12 and I've recently starting getting the following error -

```
Call to undefined method Redis::delete()
```

I have a Redis cache configuration which I'm able to write to and read. But then when I try to delete the same, I get the above error. This was not happening before. I have correctly configured the cache like below

```
Cache::config('1min', [
'engine' => CACHE_ENGINE,
'server' => CACHE_HOST,
'port' => CACHE_PORT,
'prefix' => CACHE_PREFIX,
'duration'=>'+1 minute'
]);
```

And I'm able to execute the following actions

```
Cache::write('cache1', 'value', '1min');
Cache::read('cache1', '1min');
```

without any errors. It's only when I try to delete the key using the following command

```
Cache::delete('cache1', '1min');
```

that I'm getting the above error.

I'm using phpredis which I install via .ebextensions. I'm downloading the package via this link -

```
https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/develop.zip -O phpredis.zip
```

Upon doing some research, I found that the delete function in Redis.php is deprecated as is soon going to be deleted. When I change the function call in the RedisEngine.php file (this is a CakePHP library file which gets downloaded as a dependency via composer) on line 176 from

```
public function delete($key) {
    return $this->_Redis->delete($key) > 0;
}
```

to

```
public function delete($key) {
    return $this->_Redis->del($key) > 0;
}
```

the Cache delete works correctly. This was not happening before. If I can get some assistance with this at the earliest that would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In documentation of [phpredis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/#del-delete-unlink) is written as note:

> Note: `delete` is an alias for `del` and will be removed in future versions of phpredis.

Consider using [`unlink`](https://redis.io/commands/unlink) instead of `delete` and `del` methods because [`unlink`](https://redis.io/commands/unlink) is working asynchronously and this will not block your code execution.

Note that `unlink` is available only if your redis version is equal to or bigger than 4.0.0

Comment: Hello @GTsvetanov - Thank you for your answer. I also realised the above when I went through the documentation for PHPRedis but the actual function call of 'delete' is happening from a CakePHP library file - RedisEngine.php which I download via composer. So I think this is an update that will need to be done on the CakePHP composer download?

Comment: Hello @PrathameshDatar I've made a quick check and it this is truth - https://discourse.cakephp.org/t/how-long-will-cakephp-2-x-be-supported/3880 then 2.x is no more maintained except for security fixes because 4.0 release date is in December-2019 so if you won't update you packages via composer you can directly fix the issue in vendor package (it not a good practice!). Other way is to create a PR in their git with request to fix the issue in new version of 2.x.